# Setting linespace in gVim

Tags: vim

When setting `linespace` to some value greater than zero, the characters in the line are vertically top-aligned. I want the characters to be vertically centered (in the middle of the line).

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: You reposted your own question. Try improving your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373877/chars-not-in-the-middle-of-the-line-when-setting-linespace-at-gvim) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'linespace'` setting allows to *slightly* adapt the visual spacing of lines to the used font (so that text is neither too dense nor too much apart). It is not meant to be used for the "widely-spaced lines" effect shown in your screenshot.

If you really need something like that, you'd need to patch Vim's source code, or use another editor, or what I would attempt is modifying the used font to include more vertical padding in all glyphs.